# Surface > Background > As Color using environment texture doesn't display when rendering on EEVEE

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency, glass, reflection

*Surface > Background > As Color* using environment texture doesn't display when rendering on EEVEE.

The transparency is there, the screens pace reflections activated, alpha blend mode and so on, this is the look on the render view port:

[image: Looks strange but it's not the final step!]

And this is how it looks after rendering:
[image]

This is the node setup I'm using for this object:
[image]

Finally these are my settings:
[image]

I've been stuck trying to make this work for hours, looked a dozens of posts and articles but can't find a solution